# SAS - pass a macro to a macro

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Is there a way to pass a macro as an argument to a macro ?

something like

```
%macro outer_macro(macro);
  %do i=1 %to 5;
     &macro
  %end;
%mend outer_macro;

%macro inner_macro;
  /* do something usefull */
%mend inner_macro;

%outer_macro(%inner_macro)
```

this example doesn't work, of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would use macro quoting to accomplish this.

A simple version of your example:

```
%macro outer_macro(macro);
  %put Starting outer macro;
     %unquote(&macro)  /* %unquote removes the NRSTR escape characters */
  %put Ending outer macro;
%mend outer_macro;

%macro inner_macro;
  %put Starting inner macro;
  proc print data=sashelp.class;
  run;
  %put Ending inner macro;
%mend inner_macro;

%outer_macro(%nrstr(%inner_macro)) /* %nrstr is execution-time quoting, so %inner_macro is passed and not treated as a macro until %unquote removes the quoting */
```

To involve something like a loop, you'd just make sure everything was set up to take the loop iterator - one way is simply to append ( ) with the loop.

```
%macro outer_macro(macro);
  %put Starting outer macro;
    %do i = 1 %to 19;
       %unquote(&macro)(n=&i.)  /* resolves to %inner_macro(n=&i.) */
    %end;
  %put Ending outer macro;
%mend outer_macro;

%macro inner_macro(n=);
  %put Starting inner macro;
  proc print data=sashelp.class(obs=&n. firstobs=&n.);
  run;
  %put Ending inner macro;
%mend inner_macro;

%outer_macro(%nrstr(%inner_macro))
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just pass the macro by name?

```
%macro outer_macro(macro);
  %put Starting &sysmacroname - MACRO=%superq(macro);
     %&macro
  %put Ending &sysmacroname;
%mend outer_macro;

%macro inner_macro(dsn);
  %put Starting &sysmacroname - &=dsn;
  proc print data=&dsn;
  run;
  %put Ending &sysmacroname;
%mend inner_macro;

%outer_macro(inner_macro(sashelp.class)) ;
```

Resulting LOG with MPRINT turned on.

```
Starting OUTER_MACRO - MACRO=inner_macro(sashelp.class)
Starting INNER_MACRO - DSN=sashelp.class
MPRINT(INNER_MACRO):   proc print data=sashelp.class;
MPRINT(INNER_MACRO):   run;

NOTE: There were 19 observations read from the data set SASHELP.CLASS.
NOTE: PROCEDURE PRINT used (Total process time):
      real time           0.04 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds


Ending INNER_MACRO
Ending OUTER_MACRO
```